# Is possible hide hierarchical select dropdown created by jetsmartfilters? (only visual issue)

Tags: taxonomy, dropdown, hierarchical

Is possible to hide child ("City") hierarchical select fields before parent ("State") choice? **only visual issue**. I did hide function in "JavaScript" but I couldn't join JetSmartFilters and JetEngine.  thanks, everyone.

Comment: You'll have to ask the support team for whatever plugin/theme provides "JetSmartFilters"/"JetEngine". Third-party plugin & theme support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: You've just made [a suggested edit 'claiming authorship'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/247549). That won't work. You need to [merge your old and new accounts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself!!

JetSmartFilter/Settings/Indexer Settings "active" Indexed filters at same page "choose" Index Post Types. Next go to your "page" editing with Elementor
choose select field/ configure Jet Engine and link your hierarchical filter/ and after this the most important:

inside "Select Field Edit" go to "**INDEXER OPTIONS**" / "active" apply indexer / if item empty **HIDE**/ Index Post Types "Others Filters Changed".

My Select Field parent is "State" and child "City". If you try something different you may need to adjust it according to your needs.

Thanks,everyone! Hope this helps!